# Cordova application crashes after launch [iOS]

Tags: ios, cordova, crash

I found out one issue that I am not able to find a way how to solve it. I've created one very simple app with Cordova and Framework7 template and I installed it on my iOS device.

After few days of a correct running I tried to run this app, only the splash screen appears and after a few seconds the app just turn off and I am not able to put this app to the foreground.

Is there any option how to find out why this is happening (e.g. app logs)? When I install this app again, everything is fine (for few days).

Comment: I found the solution for this issue. There is everything fine with code. My apple developer account is free and it expires after one week and it looks like the application crashes!

Comment: Last time I checked, free developer accounts allow you to install test apps with no restrictions on your registered developer device.

Comment: Yes, I checked it too. But there is an issue with the certificate and free developer account when the certificate expires after one week and this expiration date should be exactly seen int the Xcode:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51527

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I have wasted whole day but could not find the solution. Any champ here ?

Comment: Hey @Sunny_Sid that problem was with certificate that is limited to 7 days if you do not have a paid dev acc. Look at my first comment